Why does decreasing partition count prevent a StageFailure due to large size of serialized results?
I am trying to generate a randomly sorted version of a large-ish dataframe on databricks.
My go-to code is to use .orderBy(rand()) on the dataframe.
This, however, seems to trigger a SparkException quite often: SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Total size of serialized results of 36 tasks (1038.9 MiB) is bigger than spark.driver.maxResultSize 1024.0 MiB.
After experimenting a but, I see that the error goes away if I decrease the number of partitions with repartition(10) or something like this.
This is counterintuitive for me, as I expected that decreasing the number of partitions would increase the size of each chunk traveling through the network, thereby making the size of serialized results larger instead?
Could anybody explain why this isn't the case?
// BOOM
display(my_df
.orderBy(rand()))

// WORKS FINE
display(my_df
.repartition(10)
.orderBy(rand()))

PS.: the original number of partitions in my DF is 662. It's a Parquet file read straight from an S3 bucket
P.S.2: Running Spark3.3.0 with Scala 2.12 on Databricks!

Interesting issue! It seems like the data that each task sends to your driver is rather large. Is it possible that a single row of your dataframe already contains a lot of information? Maybe you have a lot of columns, long strings, or complex data types?

Yes, this dataframe has many columns! Around 50 columns IIRC

Can you share the size of your parquet file, and the number of rows in that file?

This issue is due to how the message is sent to the driver.
All the messages the workers send to the driver are serialized according to spark docs, and if you have a lot of partitions, each message will have extra information to be sent.
You reduce the partitioning from 622 to 10, and all the metadata sent with it is also reduced. Imagine you have to send 622 * 50(columns metadata), and now you are sending 10 * 50(columns metadata).

your explanation makes sense however in the error message it says that the result is from 36 tasks and not 662, I guess the metadata is significantly less

Spark internally uses accumulators for TaskMetrics & SQLMetrics. These are used to get the stats of Task / Stage / Job / SQL level metrics. Same is also used in physical plan and Spark Web UI. It might be the case that when you are using 660+ partitions these accumulators' serialized size is exceeding the 1G limit.
On the 36 tasks message, it simply means that while it was still collecting the metrics from tasks, at the 36th task it crossed the limit. In my opinion, if you do repartition(35) or repartition(30) it might work.
There were some optimization done long back in spark where names for the internal accumulators were removed from being sent. That had reduced the size significantly. But that has not resolved this error completely. But it did reduced its occurrence.
Spark driver requires large memory space for serialized results even there are no data collected to the driver
